# Windows Batch File - Using Append with File Name that has spaces

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch file to consolidate some hard coded text with a few of other existing text files.

for this I am using the below.

```
set "txtFile=.\text.txt"
call:Append "C:\test 123\test.txt" %textFile%
```

over here, when I execute it, it thros an error as it is not able to proceed with the path as it has spaces.

how should this be addressed.

Comment: Is that the code you are using? Seems to be a mismatch between `txtFile` and `textFile`...?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your append batch file is doing, but you can simply use copy to concatenate two files.

It's not clear to me what the needs to be appended to what, but the following will append the contents of `text.txt` to `C:\test 123\test.txt` by writing everything to `C:\test 123\test.txt`.

```
set txtFile=.\text.txt
copy "C:\test 123\test.txt" /a + %txtFile% /a "C:\test 123\test.txt"
```

If you want a different output file, just change the last parameter.

Btw: it's better to not rely on a specific working directory

The following:

```
set txtFile=%~dp0text.txt
```

makes sure that the `text.txt` is used that is in the same directory as your batch file.